# ngFor does not work and is providing no data

Tags: html, angular, nested, primeng, ngfor

I have to 2 nested `ngFor`, the first one works as expected, the second does not work at all.

It shows no data at all for the second.

---

Here is my code:

component.html

```html
<p-accordion *ngIf="!isLoading">
    <p-accordionTab 
      *ngFor="let userDepartment of userDepartments" 
      [header]="[userDepartment.department]">
        <a *ngFor="let user of userDepartment.users" 
          [routerLink]="[user.id]" 
          routerLinkActive="active">{{user.displayName}}</a>
    </p-accordionTab>
</p-accordion>
```

UserDepartment.ts

```js
import { SkillUser } from "./skillUser";

export interface UserDepartment{
  department: string;
  users: SkillUser[];
}
```

Comment: Could you share some console logs of `userDepartments`? And what does it mean that 1st ngFor works as expected - what is it displaying? Are there any errors?

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to answer if I could see all related codes. But try using index:

```
 *ngFor="let userDepartment of userDepartments"; let i = index"
     *ngFor="let user of userDepartment[i].users"
```